# QScintilla Custom syntax highlighting

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, ide, pyqt5, qscintilla

I need to QSCintilla highlight codes like this one: \xfffe.
After a hour of googling, i still found nothing on custom lexicon for QScintilla.

So how do i make mine custom lex with it? I already have a parser code(from old versions) here:https://github.com/OctoNezd/PokeNDSTranslator/blob/master/reader.py . But if i use it, i can`t edit, but IDE is designed to create and edit, but now it is just a viewer

Comment: Hi Nezd. Maybe this will help you out: http://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago. QScintilla is a wonderful tool, but documentation is very scarce.
I worked very hard together with my friend Matic Kukovec to change that. Please take a look at our website:

https://qscintilla.com/

It is a beginner-friendly tutorial on QScintilla and aims to explain the complete API.

Good luck!